# Android studio Timeout waiting to lock file hash cache ==> Existing solutions not working

Tags: android-studio

I can not run any existing or new Android Studio projects. After Gradle Build I get:
Timeout waiting to lock file hash cache

I am new to Android development. I have tried all of the solutions I found:

- Invalidate caches and restart
- Go to task manager and look for running instances of Android Studio
- Restart Windows
- Manually delete the project lock file
- Manually delete everything under user.gradle\caches

Since I am new I figured I might as well start over:

- Reinstalled Android studio, but it left a bunch of crap behind and still remembered my settings
- Clean reinstall;
  -- Uninstall
  -- Manually delete all folders I could find that were Android or Android studio or Gradle.
  -- Manually delete the AndroidStudio projects folder.
  -- In this case the reinstall appeared clean. However, when I created a new project I got the same error.

Can anyone suggest another approach or describe how to do a true clean install (Initially I was able to run programs so if I can get back to a clean version I should be OK).

Comment: along with the project's cache did you also try deleting the user's .gradle/caches/ folder contents?

Answer (score 0):

I did get everything to work, but I'm still not sure what is going on.

On my computer I have the standard C:\ drive and a G:\ drive created by Google File Stream. Google automatically backs up G:\ files to my online google drive. The way that file stream works, if forces the root directory to be G:\My Drive\

Anyway the gradle build works correctly if the projects are on my C:\ drive (C:\Users\UserName\AndroidStudioProjects), but I get a lock error for files on my G:\ drive (G:\My Drive\AndroidStudioProjects)

I'm not sure why the G:\ location does not work. I'm *almost* positive I had tutorial projects running on the G:\ drive at some point, but then they stopped. There is a warning about spaces in file locations having issues with the NDK (My Drive), but I don't believe that was a problem initially. One thing I am wondering about is that at some point I followed instructions to update the SDK using the SDK manager. I remember that it said that 10+ Android (R) needed to be updated. Could be something with that???